# How does a soft landing technically work without air on the moon?

Tags: rockets, the-moon

I am curious to know about how rockets or an object lands on the moon when there isn't any air (atmosphere) and the gravity is low.

Comment: yes that but how i mean how nasa's rover land on moon

Comment: Rockets don't need air to work.

Comment: related [How did skeptics of rocketry think rockets work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38022/20636)

Comment: If rocket engines would need air to get close to the Moon and to land softly, there would have been no manned and unmanned landings at all. Even reaching an orbit around the Earth would be impossible.

Comment: For soft landings on Earth and Mars a parachute may be used but not on the Moon. But if the Moon would have a much stronger gravity, the Apollo landings as done in history would have been impossible. A much larger and stronger Saturn V as well as LM would be necessary to fight the gravity of the larger Moon.

Comment: Have you seen SpaceX land rockets on Earth? It's pretty neat, and very much the same concept.

Comment: @Uwe - Naughty! Of course rocket motors need air. Try igniting one without it!! The point is, rockets carry both fuel and air, mix the two, and ignite the mixture.

Comment: @Ed999 No rocket carries air, some carry oxygen, some use other oxidators. Carring 79 % useless nitrogen would be a big waste.

Comment: And some rockets don't even use oxidants.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Rocket engines (unlike jet engines and internal combustion engines) are designed to work without drawing air from outside. A moon lander carries 2 tanks: one filled with propellant, the other one filled with an oxidiser. The rocket engine combines these two and ignites the mixture. The exhaust product provides thrust both in an atmosphere and in a vacuum. Thrust may be slightly higher in a vacuum. The thrust is used to reduce the speed of the spacecraft to near zero, enabling a soft landing.

Comment: I would prefer the sentence: the exhaust product provides thrust in air as well as in a vacuum. Thrust may be slightly higher in a vacuum.

Comment: I've amended my answer.

Comment: I prefer this answer as well, might want to include something about firing in the reverse direction of travel to slow down

Comment: a landing doesn't usually reduce the speed to zero, instead reducing to a few m/s

Comment: @jcrm I put in the correction.

Comment: I wish you hadn't. I object to "kitchen sink" answers which include far more detail than is necessary to answer the question.

Comment: It's worth noting that when the thrust of the rocket is equal to the gravitational pull between lander and Moon, then acceleration ceases, and then only slight changes in thrust are needed to change the lander's speed.  (And the lander's rocket engines are "throttle-able", a feature that is very rare in other rocket uses.)

Comment: @Hobbes If you don't like an edit to your answer, you are free to roll it back.  Personally  I wouldn't in this case; in fact I think the detail about "thrust is higher in vacuum" is much more unnecessary detail than changing "zero" to "near zero".

Answer (score 15):

Spacecrafts, including [Apollo Lunar Module (LM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) lander, use propulsion for [retroburns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrorocket), thus decreasing their velocity as they descend. This method works in the vacuum of space as well as in the atmosphere.

Comment: what do you mean by "rocket"

Comment: By rocket do you mean 'Saturn V' or all the lander entries here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon which used rockets to slow to some extent (several have crashed, one slowed and used airbags for the final 50kmh or so)

Comment: @JCRM well, to my understanding, a "rocket" is the entire machine that lifts off from Earth, particularly including the first stage which would typically reentry and burn.

Comment: ah, you mean a booster?

Comment: @GremlinWranger why would you call lander "a rocket"? Technically it contains a rocket engine, but the primary role is to land on an astronomical body of destination (sometimes to fulfill a parallel lift off function, as in Apollo LM case)

Comment: @JCRM, no, the whole assembly as it lifts off from the Earth. This is my understanding of this term as it's mostly used. What would be your definition of a rocket?

Comment: "A rocket is a missile, spacecraft, aircraft or other vehicle that obtains thrust from a rocket engine"
"A rocket also can be a type of engine"

Comment: my best guess is the OP is using rocket in the sense of "rocket engine"

Comment: @JCRM all right, with this definition anything that has a rocket engine and use it for thrust is a rocket. Would you call Soyuz reentry capsule a rocket then?

Comment: Due to the very short duration, I would go for technically yes. but I reiterate, the OP is probably using "rocket" to mean "rocket engine"

Comment: @GremlinWranger I have updated the first paragraph in an attempt to not "sound as an Apollo conspiracy". Is it better now?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, a moon lander does count as a rocket.

Answer (score 4):

Rockets thrust works because of conservation of momentum, which is a fundamental law of our universe. When hot gasses are pushed out of the rocket, they exchange momentum with the rocket in the opposite direction. As a result, rockets don't need to "push" against anything on the business end. It's often misunderstood as a wing or helicopter rotors "pushing" against the air, but that isn't how rockets function. For some chemical rockets, if they require an oxidizer that is needed for creating hot gases, then it is carried inside the rocket.

Comment: "For some chemical rickets that require an oxidizer needed for creating hot gases is carried inside the rocket" ????  I think you mean "rockets", and the sentence is still poorly-constructed.